# No mobile site for the election

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, election, mobile-web

When going to the [election](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election) page on a mobile device (iPod touch) it takes me to desktop version of the page, and clicking the mobile button doesn't do anything.

If this is by design, please remove the mobile button at least.

Comment: ...which mobile button? The one in the footer?

Comment: @NickCraver That's the one.

Comment: this need to be fixed people want to see my election post even on theire mobile devices :O

Comment: There are a number of pages that don't have a mobile version - review, flags (I think), ...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Elections may eventually get a mobile theme, however it's fairly low on the priority list.  Vote this up to show your support.