# Advert to the election on the mobile site too

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, election

The information that there's an election at the moment is quite present on the full [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) site:

[image: SO main page]

But when browsing mobile you'll not even notice that something is going on, except you switch to the full site or a page where the full site is always triggered like [About](https://stackoverflow.com/about).

I guess it's a little late for this year's moderator election but maybe it's useful for upcoming events if this information is also present on the mobile site. It should not be displayed all the time. But it could be brought up at any new phase (*nomination*, *primary* and *election*) and can have a *dismiss* button to hide it until the next phase has started. I think a reminder like this is helpful to address more people.

Here's a mockup how it could look like:

[image: mobile mockup]

Comment: +1 for `Don't miss it Participate now`

Comment: One related problem: The election page itself is not yet mobile-enabled. That would likely need to be done before there are links to it on the mobile site.

Comment: @AndrewBarber There's already a discussion on that topic: [No mobile site for the election](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120962/190341). But I think this is not something that must be done first, as the full page and therefor the election page too work fine on mobiles.